# copying amazon s3 blobs to azure blobs

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy my amazon s3 blobs to azure blobs via this [code on github](https://github.com/kpfaulkner/azurecopy)

I am using this query with my own amazon/azure blobs instead of test

```
azurecopy.exe -i "https://testurl.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myfile.txt" -o "https://azuretest.blob.core.windows.net/test/"
```

I have only changed the keys in the app config

```
<add key="AzureAccountKey" value=""/>
<add key="AWSAccessKeyID" value=""/>
<add key="AWSSecretAccessKeyID" value=""/>
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1"/>
```

but it always gives me this error

```
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

at this line of code in AzureBlobCopyHandler class in StartCopy function

```
var res = blob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(url));
```

I know it's something wrong in the parameters but I have been following the code and can't find something wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest tracing the request/response through Fiddler. That should give your some more information.

Comment: StartCopyFromBlob is an Azure SDK call, so the error is clear ... that blob isn't there.  If you are able to debug, I'd breakpoint there and see what that url variable is.  Then use some Azure storage client GUI to take a look.  If that URL is good, check the blob object itself, see what its URL is.  One of those two hasn't been created.  Not sure if thats your error or in this code

Comment: What happens when you copy the Amazon S3 object URL in browser's address bar? Do you still get 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it yourself. Sure Azure doesn't understand S3 blob format. But you can read metadata from AWS manually and use it to create the Azure blob, and then use download URL or Stream API in S3 to get the file contents to the Azure blob (I think there is an API you can send the download URL to create the blob from without going via local machine).

Answer (score 0):

Now that I look into the github thingy I suppose it should understand both S3 and Azure format. But not sure whether it works at all. I'd get the source code, modify the program to use hard coded URLs (or create a unit test that hardcodes them), and then F5/debug-test, then see in debugger what exception is thrown when doing what.